# How to avoid "RTFM" answers if you can't ask where to find the documentation?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Twice now I've asked for recommendations for resources to solve my own problem, and twice now my question has been deleted.

Over the years, I have grown tired of people telling me to [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM). So now generally, when I'm learning a new skill, rather than ask someone how to do a thing, I ask where to find the information to do said thing.

That is, apparently, illegal here - or at least on Stack Overflow.

So, to my question, which I have had to rephrase already twice to avoid doing the same thing again:

How should a relative beginner approach Stack Overflow? When searching does not bring up an answer, there are usually two (occasionally three) reasons.

1. The answer seems obvious to seasoned developers
2. What the questioner wants to do is a branch of the tree that started with bad practice, so nobody does it because they would've done X three steps ago
3. It's a novel problem that few people have had to solve.

Obviously, we all hope our question is a 3, but realistically 3's are zebras in a corral full of horses. So when I search Google and Stack Overflow for an answer to my problem, and I find none, I assume my problem is a 1 or 2. My general move with a 1 or 2 question is to ask for resources, rather than to ask for help. That doesn't work here.

What is my approach, then? Let's assume I've read any docs and consumed any "manual" I am familiar with. Should I just ask my question anyway, and button up and prepare to get a whole bunch of RTFM responses, hoping that perhaps someone will couch an answer inside their derision?

Is Stack Overflow perhaps the wrong resource? I will refrain from asking what other resources one might suggest because my fingers are still tingling from the last time I touched that wire.

Comment: This appears to be specific to Stack Overflow, and as such, is better off deleted here and posted on that site's [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: If you’ve already read the manual etc, is there a reason you can’t explain what you’ve learned from that manual in a question asking how to do something? _After reading x I thought y would do z, but it didn’t_ kind of thing?

Comment: @cigien OP can not re-post this as-is on MSO yet, they haven't earned the reputation necessary for that privilege. While I agree it is off-topic here, your suggestion of re-posting on MSO also isn't viable, unless this can be linked to a specific question. The system will ask you which question it is about and include a link to that, IIRC.

Comment: Stephen, if you anticipate that many people will answer "Do X" then why not do it first, and then in your question explain what you have tried already: "I've read *The Fine Manual*, section ?.? on Subject Y,  and I can't find out how to do Z". - then people can answer that you should have read a different section, or looked at a different manual. --- You are lucky if that's the answer half the time, as you only need to ask 1/2 as many questions. --- You can answer your own question, and prove the *experts* wrong.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Oh, I didn't realize that, my bad. Would migrating the post to MSO make sense? I'm not sure if OP will be able to comment, etc on that post with their rep.

Comment: @cigien migrating wouldn't make sense either no, that would be abusing moderator powers to circumvent system restrictions :/

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I wouldn't go so far as to call it abuse, but I see your point :) So what's the procedure in cases like this? Does this question just get closed as off-topic, or is it borderline enough to be allowed to stay open here?

Comment: @cigien I'll leave that up to the close-vote queue.

Comment: at MSO this would likely be closed as duplicate of [Is there a good place to find centralized information on tutorials and helpful tools, and how should questions for such be handled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297554/839601)

Comment: RTFM is never ever acceptable. There is never any need to say it. It doesn't serve any purpose. It is not constructive. All beginner questions have already been asked, so point to the appropriate Stack Overflow question (with the answer). Alternatively, close as too broad or off-topic.

Comment: Your questions are much better than ending them with the broad and unspecific *"Anyone have any good info?"*. End them with the specific question instead (even if it is somewhat redundant with the title - the body ought to be self-contained). Call to action is implied by posting the question - there isn't any need to say it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My general move with a 1 or 2 question is to ask for resources, rather than to ask for help.

Right. As you already found out, that doesn't fly.

> Let's assume I've read any docs and consumed any "manual" I am familiar with

We don't assume anything. We see so many *I've looked anywhere but found nothing* claims but putting one or two keywords into a search engine, even the crappy one on SE, returns plenty of results.

We not only expect you to do [plenty of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) but also **include that in your question**. And then describe and show (we love code!) what the problem is you're trying to solve.

When you include *I searched for Foo and Bar and found FooBar but when used that didn't work due to unicorn explosions* experienced users will notice you should have searched for Fu and Bar because that gives you waffles and those don't detonate. They might provide an answer explaining the differences between Foo and Fu and the proper usage of Fu and solve the specific problem you stated. As a bonus they link you to extra resources to further educate yourself. Upvote worthy content.

The result of such question and their answers is that any future visitor can now relate their problem and **search terms / keywords** to yours. When they match they have found their problem and the solution. An happy future visitor returns to the site later for more goodies.

This approach/success story does put more burden on the wording of your  question but that is a price we happily pay as so many visitors after you will benefit from a question that is findable by keywords only users new to a certain technology would use.

Comment: I disagree that "We don't assume anything." The attitude on SO/SE seems to be to assume that question-askers are lazy and stupid at best or malicious time-wasters at worst. Stephen Wight appears to be a victim of that assumption.

Comment: @ClementCherlin you're free to think that. My personal opinion is that we're more focused on content and less on who asked something. At best the question is the victim.

Comment: @ClementCherlin it's not an assumption, but a conclusion.  Several times I have asked OP's to post the search strings they tried before posting their question so that better ones might be suggested.  The result?  100% the OP does not reply and the question goes dead:(

Comment: @rene The question was presumably asked by *a person* who is interested in the answer. Furthermore, gratuitous downvotes decrease *a person's* account's rep. Content does not exist in a vacuum, it exists solely for the benefit of *people*. The high-rep consensus appears to be that high-quality content matters, *people don't*.

Comment: @MartinJames A conclusion, based on past experiences, which leads to an assumption about future events...which is to say, an assumption.

Comment: Umm.. OK, so it was originally a hypothesis.  Experimentation was done which 100% supported the hypothesis.  So, I can call it 'The James Theory':)

Comment: The James Theory: 'The more stridently a poster claims that they have done diligent research, the more likely it is that they have done none'.